# Java classes.jar' could not be found error when executing maven

Tags: java, macos, maven

I just installed java 8 and maven on Mac El Captain. I have set all the environment variables correctly and java -version does display the java version. But when I try to run maven from the terminal I get the following error:

```
File or url '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Classes/classes.jar' could not be found
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Classes/classes.jar
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.loadFileOrUrl(Forehead.java:403)
    at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.load(Forehead.java:322)
    at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.config(Forehead.java:245)
    at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.config(Forehead.java:131)
    at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.main(Forehead.java:579)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed JDK or JRE ?

Comment: Hi there, I used this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html I think this contains both

Comment: Do you have a system scope dependency to classes.jar ? Please show your pom file...

Comment: This is not in an application. This is simply just entering mvn in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

For Maven 1.x, I found the following bit of the `bin/maven` shell script caused the same error for me on a Mac:

```
if $darwin; then
    TOOLS_JAR="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/${JAVA_VERSION}/Classes/classes.jar"
fi
```

I simply edited the `bin/maven` script file and commented out the `if $darwin; then ... fi` section and it is now working.

Comment: I had the same problem, this fixed it for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The pass where classes

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Classes/classes.jar
```

I would guess its 'JavaVM.framework' or really amissing protocol like 'file:'

If you installed the JDK in a path like JavaVM.framework, try to installit in another path without '.'